# bash script: prompt for user input while stdout and stderr may have been redirected externally

Tags: bash

Some commands bypass the shell's stdout and stderr redirections; for example:

```
sudo echo > /dev/null 2>&1
Password:
```

I would like to achieve the same behavior in a script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS='' read -r -p 'Your input: ' input
```

```sh
./script.sh > script.log 2>&1
Your input:
```

How can you do that (preferably in a portable way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection applies to the `echo` command.

`time`, however, is not a command at all; it's a precommand modifier, whose output is written by the shell itself. (Even when `echo` is a shell built-in command, it is still treated like an ordinary command whose stdout and stderr are inherited from the shell.)

The password prompt, on the other hand, is written by some command directly to the *terminal*, not standard error.

---

For your updated question, note that `read -p` writes to standard error, not the terminal. You can typically write to the terminal by redirecting output to `/dev/tty`.

```
echo "Your input: " > /dev/tty
IFS='' read -r input
```

Comment: Alright, `time` wasn't a good example. I need something like the password prompt of sudo, ssh, etc... Let's say that the target OSs are macOS and Linux, how do you write text to an ANSI terminal from the shell (with commonly available tools)?

Comment: Typically, you can redirect output to `/dev/tty`.